$T_1$ first countable spaces and well-ordered countable local pseudobases
Let $X$ be a $T_1$ first countable space, and let $x \in X$.
Let $\mathcal{B} = \{B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a countable basis of neighborhoods of $x$ in $X$. As, $x$ is the intersection of all its neighborhoods, then $\bigcap \mathcal{B} = \{x\}$.
Let $\mathcal{U} = \{B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a collection of neighborhoods of $x$ in $X$, such that $\bigcap \mathcal{B} = \{x\}$. Then, we can build a countable collection of neighborhoods of $x$ totally ordered by inclusion, and such that its intersection is $x$, as follows: $\mathcal{V} = \{C_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $C_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_n$.
If $\mathcal{U}$ is a basis of neighborhoods of $x$, then $\mathcal{V}$ is also a basis of neighborhoods of $x$ (if $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $B_n \subseteq A$, and we know that $C_n \subseteq B_n$).
I wanted to know an example of a $T_1$ first countable space where there exists a point having a countable collection of open neighborhoods that is totally ordered by inclusion, and that the intersection of the whole collection is the point, but that it isn't a basis of neighborhoods of the point.

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ first countable space, and let $x \in X$.
Suppose that there exists $Y$, being a strictly coarser $T_1$ first countable space than $X$.
Then there exists a point $x \in Y$ such that every neighborhood basis of $x$ in $Y$ isn't a neighborhood basis of $x$ in $X$.
Otherwise, if every point of $Y$ has a neighborhood basis in $Y$ that is also a neighborhood basis in $X$, then each open set of $X$ is an union of open sets of $Y$, and, therefore, it is open in $Y$.
From the results of the question, there exists a countable basis of neighborhoods of $x$ in $Y$ totally ordered by inclusion, and it verifies that its intersection is the point. However, it isn't a basis of neighborhoods of $x$ in $X$.
Examples: $Y = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology, or $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the Sorgenfrey topology.
Note: we deduce that if a $T_1$ space $X$ that has countable pseudocharacter verifies that every countable collection of open sets that (1) is totally ordered by inclusion, and that (2) the intersection of the whole collection is a point $x$, is a neighborhood basis of $x$, then $X$ is first countable, and it doesn't have strictly coarser $T_1$ first countable spaces.
